# Finding the amplitude of function solved using ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, physics, parametric-functions

I have been trying to find the peaks of a function I have plotted using ParametricNDSolve. I have to find these peaks to calculate the amplitude of all the various waves in the observed output. By amplitude here I mean the difference between an adjacent crest and trough. I shall attach the program here to clarify the problem.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
om = 1;
k = 1;
L = 1/1000;
P = 1.3;

eqns = {a'[t] == 
I*((de/om)*a[t] - (b[t] + Conjugate[b[t]])*a[t] - 
    1/2) - (k/(2*om))*a[t], 
b'[t] == -I*((P*(Abs[a[t]])^2)/2 + b[t]) - (L/(2*om))*b[t], 
b[0] == 0, a[0] == 0};

s = ParametricNDSolve[eqns, {a, b}, {t, 0, 100}, de, 
MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]];

x[de_][t_] = (b[de][t] + Conjugate[b[de][t]]) /. s;

Manipulate[
Plot[x[de][t], {t, 0, 99}, PlotRange -> {-4, 4}], {de, -3, 3, .1, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Now I have to find the value of the amplitude of x for every value of de that I have plotted. While I have been able to find the peaks for individual values of de and a single peak in for these values, I have been unable to find all the peaks and amplitudes for all the values of de. I used various function including FindPeaks[] to try to find such values but was unable to do so. Normally I would have used for loops but that seems to advised against in Mathematica. I would also like to know whether such a code would be unwieldy and whether I use brute force to find such values.

I would be very grateful to anyone who could help me solve this dilemma. I would like to thank you for it beforehand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easiest to detect the extrema within the `NDSolve` using `WhenEvent`.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
om = 1; k = 1; L = 1/1000; P = 1.3;
tmax = 10000;

eqns = {
  a'[t] == I*((de/om)*a[t] - (b[t] + Conjugate[b[t]])*a[t] - 1/2) - (k/(2*om))*a[t], 
  b'[t] == -I*((P*(Abs[a[t]])^2)/2 + b[t]) - (L/(2*om))*b[t], 
  b[0] == b0, a[0] == a0,
  WhenEvent[b'[t] + Conjugate[b'[t]] == 0, Sow[{t, b[t] + Conjugate[b[t]]}]]
};

de = -3;
{a0, b0} = {0, 0};
{s, ex} = Reap[NDSolve[eqns, {a, b}, {t, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]][[1]]];
```

```
(* plot saved extrema *)
ListPlot[ex[[1]], AxesLabel -> {"t", "extrema"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you're interested in the long-term behavior, then it looks like `tmax>100` is probably a good idea.

Then you can loop over `de`, saving the difference between the last two extrema as the amplitude (assuming a simple cycle) and using the final values of `a` and `b` as initial conditions for the next value of `de`.

```
Clear[de];
{a0, b0} = {a[tmax], b[tmax]} /. s;
tmax = 1000;
res = {};
Do[
  {s, ex} = Reap[NDSolve[eqns, {a, b}, {t, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]][[1]]];
  {a0, b0} = {a[tmax], b[tmax]} /. s; (* save final values *)
  AppendTo[res, {de, Abs[ex[[1, -1, 2]] - ex[[1, -2, 2]]]}];
, {de, -3, 3, 0.1}];
```

```
(* plot amplitude vs de *)
ListPlot[res, AxesLabel -> {"de", "amp"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

That jump at `de = 0.7` makes me think there might be alternative attractors.  Indeed, if we generate the bifurcation diagram starting at `de = 3` and moving towards lower `de`, we get a different result.

```
de = 3;
tmax = 10000;
{a0, b0} = {0, 0};
{s, ex} =  Reap[NDSolve[eqns, {a, b}, {t, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]][[1]]];

Clear[de];
{a0, b0} = {a[tmax], b[tmax]} /. s;
tmax = 1000;
res = {};
Do[
  {s, ex} = Reap[NDSolve[eqns, {a, b}, {t, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]][[1]]];
  {a0, b0} = {a[tmax], b[tmax]} /. s;
  AppendTo[res, {de, Abs[ex[[1, -1, 2]] - ex[[1, -2, 2]]]}];
, {de, 3, -3, -0.1}];
```

```
ListPlot[res, AxesLabel -> {"de", "amp"}, PlotStyle -> Orange]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So a full understanding of the model's dynamics will require a bit of care!

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, hopefully helpful:

Trying to visualize your problem I get

```
pic=Plot3D[x[de][t], {t, 0, 99}, {de, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {-4, 4},MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image]

a surface with many peaks.

If you split the region `t,de` `NMaximize` finds the global(!) peak in the subregion

```
NMaximize[{x[de][t], 0 < t < 10, -3 < de < 3}, {t, de}]
(*{0.042377, {de -> 2.20983, t -> 5.55602}}*)
```